# How to use progressBar.js to draw a circle within a circle?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I am using progressBar.Circle, and this is my code that draws a single circle:

```
function AnimateCircle(container_id, animatePercentage,type) {
    var startColor = '#FFFFFF';
    var endColor = '#F18F01';

    var element = document.getElementById(container_id);
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle(element, {
        color: startColor,
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 3,
        duration: 1400,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        text: {
            value: "<h4>"+type+"</h4>"+ "<h4>"+(animatePercentage )*10+ "</h1>",
            className: 'progressbar__label'
        },

        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function (state, circle) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        }
    });

    circle.animate(animatePercentage, {
        from: {
            color: startColor
        },
        to: {
            color: endColor
        }
    });

    circle.path.style.strokeLinecap = 'round';
}
```

Is there a way for me to draw another circle within it? That would result in something similar to this:

[image]